# C# console app finishing with code 0 instead of providing the output it's supposed to calculate

Tags: c#

The program is supposed to calculate compound interest by getting several inputs from the user and then applying those with the compound interest formula, however while gramatically correct, the program does everything correctly except for ouputting the calculated value. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
   using System;

   namespace compoundCalc
  {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter investment sum:");
            int investment = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter annual interest rate:");
            double interestRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the number of times per year that interest is compounded per period:");
            int compoundNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the number of periods the money is invested for:");
            int investmentPeriod = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double nt = Math.Pow((compoundNumber * investmentPeriod),(1+interestRate / compoundNumber ));
            double futureCapital = investment * nt;
            Console.WriteLine("The future value of your investment is:",  Convert.ToString(futureCapital));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your program is correctly outputting your result, has nothing more to do, and _correctly_ terminates itself.... add a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end to force user input before the program ends.

Comment: What do you mean by "finishing with code 0" exactly?

Comment: You can also open a console separately (visual studio command console, powershell, etc) and change directories to your bin\Debug folder and run it there.  That way, you'll see the output even after the application closes.  That can make for a faster development process so you don't have to hit F5 or Shift F5 each time and see the window pop up and then disappear.

Comment: @DavidG That's what cmd puts out after the program runs its course. It doesn't put out the answer as it's supposed to but just exits like that. The window stays open, so that's not the issue I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(String, Object)` method signature requires the string [include a format character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string), which you don't have.

If you want to use [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), then that would look like

```
Console.WriteLine($"The future value of your investment is: {futureCapital}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the Console where to display the futureCapital add this `{0}` to last of your string

```
Console.WriteLine("The future value of your investment is: {0}",Convert.ToString(futureCapital));
```

or you can use [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings) `+`

```
Console.WriteLine("The future value of your investment is: " + futureCapital);
```

or more convenient use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) `$`

```
Console.WriteLine($"The future value of your investment is:{futureCapital}");
```

Comment: The first option works, using string contenation doesn't seem to though. Thanks!